# Creating an EF model programmatically from a database schema in production (without VS ecosystem)

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, data-access-layer

I'd like to leverage EF as a DAL in my application (product).

A feature in my application allows creating a database schema while the product is live in production.

I'd like to create EF model from this database, once this schema is realized in the database. Further, I should be able to reflect database schema changes (although very rare) on to the model.

The regular **database to model** approach is ruled out since the production environment lacks Visual Studio setup.

The **code first** approach doesn't quite fit the bill because of its **code first migration** feature is still in beta.

What are my choices here?

Answer (score 0):

I think the whole EF doesn't fit in your solution because you forget for the main problem. Even if you will be able to define database mapping in runtime you will still need classes where your new tables should be map and you will need code using that new classes. If you change something in table (for example change data type of column or add column) your existing class will have to be changed as well. How will you do that at runtime?

Comment: The data schema will follow a pattern; it has a hierarchical structure, i.e. the main entity is at the top and thereafter there are sub-entities that will fall in one or the other level. Each node in the tree will map (not necessary) to a table. I will therefore reference the entities via pattern based traversal logic. This will ensure that any change in the database, if reflected in the model will not have any challenge from traversal standpoint. My primary need therefore it the ability to generate model and keep it in sync with the database. Ladislav, what is your opinion now?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your structure because now I doubt it is even possible to map with EF without any dynamic behavior.

Comment: Ladislav ... I'm sorry if I am ambiguous. However I have a design in mind and wanting to achieve my objective by connecting some dots. Therefore I'll appreciate if you could let me know whether it is possible to programmatically generate an EF model from an existing database.

Comment: Classes for generating all parts of mapping should be in `System.Data.Entity.Design` (in the assembly with the same name). I don't fully understand what you are trying to do so check them yourselves if you find anything helpful.